# Unable to add model to backbone collection at specified index

Tags: javascript, collections, model, indexing, marionette

Hi I am trying to add a model to my backbone collection to a specific index i.e. index = 0

I am using the following code to do so

```
updatePosts: (postModel) ->
  @postsCollection.add(postModel, {at: 0})
```

However, the {at: 0} did not seem to take effect as my model will still appear at the bottom of my list

Initial display of collection (2 items) before adding a new modal:

[image]

After adding a new 'postModel':

[image]

As you can see the latest model with text "Completed 'Recorded all my meals' today" appeared at the bottom of the list instead of the top.

How can I resolve this so that the latest added model will always appear on top of the list?

Answer (score 1):

- try looking at the collection object itself, is it in-fact adding to index 0 or not.
- try re-rendering the entire collection after (to see if its just render item)
- if both of those fail try a sorted list  (info below)

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Adding-support-for-sorted-collections